# What is the "equivalent" of Gaussian distribution on a segment and on a circle

Tags: probability-distributions

Does there exist a probability density distribution function with analogous properties to those of the Gaussian distribution, but defined on domains such as:

1. a limited segment 
   $$x \in [a,b]$$
2. a circular domain (a domain which "wraps around")
   $$\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$$

By asking "properties similar to the Gaussian", I would ideally like something as the central limit theorem.

Comment: For 2. check out [von Mises distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_distribution) also known as the circular normal distribution.

Comment: You might also want to look at central limit theorems in free probability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you are looking for

1. [von Mises distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_distribution)
2. [Wrapped normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_normal_distribution)